# How we will take the keys from a json in the original order?

Tags: json, python-2.7, robotframework

I have a JSON file, I want to process that JSON data as Key, value pair.

Here is my JSON file

````
```"users" : {
        "abc": {
            "ip": "-------------",
            "username": "users@gmail.com",
            "password": "---------",
            "displayname": "-------",
            "Mode": "-----",
            "phonenumber": "1********1",
            "pstndisplay": "+1 *******5"
        },
        "efg": {
            "ip": "-------------",
            "username": "user1@gmail.com",
            "password": "---------",
            "displayname": "-------",
            "Mode": "-----",
            "phonenumber": "1********1",
            "pstndisplay": "+1 *******5"
        },
        "xyz": {
            "ip": "-------------",
            "username": "user2@gmail.com",
            "password": "---------",
            "displayname": "-------",
            "Mode": "-----",
            "phonenumber": "1********1",
            "pstndisplay": "+1 *******5"```
````

here i tried to get json data

````
 ``` ${the file as string}=    Get File    ${users_json_path}
  ${parsed}=    Evaluate  json.loads("""${the file as string}""")    json
  ${properties}=  Set Variable  ${parsed["users"]}
  Log  ${properties}
  :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{properties}
  \  ${sub dict}=    Get From Dictionary    ${properties}    ${key}
  \  Log  ${sub dict}
  \  Signin  ${sub dict}[ip]   ${sub dict}[username]   ${sub dict}[password]  ${sub dict}[Mode]
  \  Log  ${key} is successfully signed in.
````

Expected Behavior - The keys what I am parsing should be in sequence from JSON file. For example, abc will get a sign in first then efg and xyz.

```
${key} = abc
${key} = efg
${key} = xyz
```

Below are the questions:
1) How we will take users from JSON in sequence? Right now it is taking randomly
2) What will be the best logic to achieve that?

Comment: Dictionaries are not guaranteed to be in any particular order. You'll likely have to parse the original string manually. That, or change the back end software to return a list of dictionaries rather than a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: @BryanOakley - how to achieve this in robot framework ? Will you give any example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you tagged the question with python 2.7 - where Bryan Oakely's comment fully holds true, the elements are in random order.
If you upgrade to python 3 though, starting from v3.6 onwards the dictionaries are guaranteed to preserve the insertion order. Thus on parsing it with the json library the result will be the same as in the source string/file.

Alternatively, in v2 you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) to accomplish the same - plus, specifying the `object_pairs_hook` argument to [JSONDecoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) - with it you'll basically specify the result will be `OrderedDict`:

```
${parsed}=    Evaluate  json.loads("""${the file as string}""", object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)    json, collections
```

Comment: i didn't understand this object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict.WIl you please explain with little detailed code in RF

Comment: That's actually python, and this - the `Evaluate` call, is the extend of RF code, there's nothing more to add on the Robot Framework side :). Follow the link I've placed for the `JSONDecoder`, it has the documentation for `object_pairs_hook`, and what it does. Simplified, with it the generated object will not be a simple `dict`, but an `OrderedDict` - a dictionary where the keys' original order is preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, it's working right now.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

def main():
    json_str = """
    {
        "users" : {
            "abc": {
                "ip": "-------------",
                "username": "users@gmail.com",
                "password": "---------",
                "displayname": "-------",
                "Mode": "-----",
                "phonenumber": "1********1",
                "pstndisplay": "+1 *******5"
            },
            "efg": {
                "ip": "-------------",
                "username": "user1@gmail.com",
                "password": "---------",
                "displayname": "-------",
                "Mode": "-----",
                "phonenumber": "1********1",
                "pstndisplay": "+1 *******5"
            }
        }
    }
    """
    json_object = json.loads(json_str)
    for line in json_str.split('\n'):
        if '"' in line and ':' in line and '{' in line and '"users"' not in line:
            key = line.split('"')[1]
            print(key, json_object['users'][key])
```

Comment: This can break in so many ways... For instance if the producer generates a line like this - `"Mode": "-----",{`. Or if the json is minimized one - a single line of chars. At least add in the if block another check - `if key in json_object['users']`, and print just then.